# Confirm Dialog Box

Tags: javascript

I want to change the names of `Ok` and `Cancel` in Confirm Dialog box to `Yes` and `No`.

Comment: see example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457750/form-confirm-before-submit/12357337#12357337

Answer (score 4):

Use Jquery Dialog.

its litte hard when you start learning JQuery but believe me 
After some time you will love it..

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation  this will do what you wants..

Answer (score 1):

This is defined by the browser, and not doable by using the default confirm() dialog.

You could create your own dialog box, possibly using a framework such as jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: this is the right answer, others try to find an alternative and **that box wont look like as the confirm dialog box**.